# What is the best way to handle geometries between Python functions?

Tags: python, ogr, file-formats

What is the best way to handle geometries between different Python functions?
For example:
I have a function that exports a line from grass.script. The line will be a parameter of another function where it will be passed in.

Is it best to export them to WKT, or safe them in a GPX, or GeoJSON? The formats OGR offers are endless. But which one is most recommended?

Comment: ?  Just pass the OGRGeometry into the next function?  Python doesn't care what the type is as long as it has those attributes you need to use.

Comment: @NathanW I edited my Question. In my case I export it with Grass `v.out.ogr`. So I cannot just use the OGRGeometry.

Comment: depends on your source object and the target. For instance i wrote my self some neat little functions to convert geometry objects between `QGsGeometry` and the `gdal-geometry` class and vice-versa. If you just wanna export your geometries than i would suggest you save them to wkt. It can easily be edited and loaded into QGIS if necessary